# Load icons from UWP-library as image in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, uwp, resources, xamarin.uwp

I have the following situation:

1. We have / build an Xamarin.Forms library, that also should include our common icons
2. This icons should be used in XAML ages in this library but also in the final apps

**Library structure**

```
Base.Library (.Net Standard 2.0 + Xamarin.Forms)
|- Views (XAML)
Base.Library.Android
|- Resources
    |- drawables
        |- icon.xml
Base.Library.iOS
|- Assets
    |- icon (image asset with 3 resolutions)
Base.Library.Upw
|- Icons
    |- icon.scale-100.png
    |- ...
    |- icon.scale-400.png
```

The icons work on iOS and Android without problem (in XAML page of the ibrary project and in the final app project, that uses the library).

```
<Image WidthRequest="24" HeightRequest="24" VerticalOptions="Center"
       HorizontalOptions="End">
    <Image.Source>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
            <On Platform="Android,iOS" Value="icon" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Icons/icon.png" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Only UWP doesn't work. Is the a special syntax to load images from libraries?

I already tried the following:

```
// Prefixed with assembly name of the library
Value="ms-appx:///Base.Library.Uwp/Icons/icon.png"

// Prefixed with namespace of the library
Value="ms-appx:///Base.Library.Uwp.Namespace/Icons/icon.png"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

If I have `ms-appx:///` in the value, this is treated as `UriImageSource` instead of `FileImageSource`. If I cut this away and use the **full** path to the icon (incl. assembly name), the icons is also shown for UWP.

```
<Image WidthRequest="24" HeightRequest="24" VerticalOptions="Center"
       HorizontalOptions="End">
    <Image.Source>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
            <On Platform="Android,iOS" Value="icon" />
            <!-- Icon name prefixed with assembly name -->
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Base.Library.Uwp/Icons/icon.png" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```